# Javasound: AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream fails on server, works in client code

Tags: java, audio, javasound

My application involves uploading a wave file via a web UI, converting format to 8k, 8 bit mulaw and storing it on the server. My code is failing on the server when trying to do:

```
final AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream( in );
```

The error is:

```
Caused by: javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input stream
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1102) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
```

So I scaled back to a simple test case where I try to load the audio file as a local file:

```
final File audioFile = new File("/path/to/audio.wav");
final InputStream in = new FileInputStream( file );
final AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream( in );
```

This works.
I then went back to my server side and added some debugging like so:

```
    final byte[] audio = IOUtils.toByteArray( in );
    final File audioLog = File.createTempFile( "audiolog", ".wav" );
    IOUtils.write( audio, new FileOutputStream( audioLog ) );
    s_logger.info( "File logged to: " + audioLog.getAbsolutePath() );
    final InputStream byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream( audio );
    final AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream( byteIn );
```

This fails in the exact same way.

I then compare the original file that was uploaded against the audio file logged on the server and they are identical, right down to the checksum:

```
$ cksum uploaded.wav 
4019972581 84076 uploaded.wav 
$ cksum audiolog6415586848170376004.wav 
4019972581 84076 audiolog6415586848170376004.wav
```

Any ideas what may be going on? My server side code run on JBoss 7.1.

Thanks.

-Raj

Comment: It's likely that the server doesn't have the drivers and/or hardware to play the audio

Comment: Unlikely. The server is not required to play back. Also, the code is failing at the point where the audio is being analyzed.

Comment: No, but you're trying to open the audio file, presumably for playback, on the server...

Comment: It's also possible that the InputStream is corrupt or contains more data then just the audio...

Comment: The exception means there are no `AudioFileReader` classes registered via the SPI interface which can handle the file. I think `com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileReader` would normally handle your file, maybe you don't have this for some reason.

Comment: Hi Greg - this sounds promising. However, I run the code on the same machine. This fails only when executing inside JBoss 7.1. It works when run as a standalone (junit test) application. Any idea how JBoss 7.1 might be messing with AudioSystem?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: The input stream is not corrupt as established by comparing a checksum of saved bytes against the file contents. This is towards the end of my post.

Comment: is `in` a buffered stream?  AFAIR they have to be, for Java Sound.

Comment: Hi @AndrewThompson: I have tried buffering the stream and even reading off a file directly.

Comment: Just to test what file format providers you have installed in either environment, you could check with `com.sun.media.sound.JDK13Services.getProviders(javax.sound.sampled.spi.AudioFileReader.class)`. It provides the list of providers also used by `AudioSystem`. Another approach would be to set a breakpoint in the `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream()` method and check which providers fail/are available.

Comment: can you share the "getAudioInputStream" mthod

Answer (score 1):

The following might be worth trying.

The *InputStream* intermediate step does various tests that can throw an *IOException* if they fail. From the [api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html#getAudioInputStream%28java.io.File%29):

> The implementation of this method may require multiple parsers to
>   examine the stream to determine whether they support it. These parsers
>   must be able to mark the stream, read enough data to determine whether
>   they support the stream, and, if not, reset the stream's read pointer
>   to its original position. If the input stream does not support these
>   operation, this method may fail with an *IOException*.

I recommend avoiding the InputStream step altogether and set yourself up to load via **AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(File)** or **AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(URL)**. These two do not have this requirement.

I will admit, though, this does not jibe with your writing that the error thrown was *UnsupportedAudioFileException*, and that you were able to load using this method as a "local file". The way in which these tests are implemented could be different in the different circumstances.

Comment: Thanks @Phil. This did not work wither. I think JBoss is messing with the audio SPI. I am not sure how, though ...

Comment: Did you get the same error message when using the URL form (that one is my preferred choice)? I'm thinking the wording would be slightly different, given that the URL form does not make use of InputStream, and the wording references InputStream.

Comment: At this point I have the exact same piece of code that loads a file and tries to get an audio input stream from it. When this code is run as a standalone Java application, it works. When this exact code is run within a JBoss 7.1 (running locally in debug mode), it fails. I am thinking this is JBoss interfering with the audio SPI.

Comment: Ah, I understand that the same code that works one way does not work the other. My question: (a) does the URL method generate an error message under JBoss? (b) What is the error message? If you don't wish to pursue this line of inquiry, so be it. But I am thinking JBoss is reputable and is probably going to give us some clues with its error messages. Also, in case I wasn't clear, the manner and circumstances in which InputLine->AudioInputLine fails has been unpredictable. It used to work for audio in Java 6 and only started failing in Java 7 due to changes in implementation.

Comment: Which brings up this question: what Java version is JBoss running on? What Java version is your standalone JVM? They very well may be different versions which could give clues as to the different responses. Your JBoss isn't running on Java 6 by any chance is it?