# Could not get audio input stream from file

Tags: java, audio

We use the following code in our application to try to read the duration of an MP3 file:

```
final File file = new File(filename);
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
```

While trying to get an AudioInputStream out of a file an UnsupportedAudioFileException is thrown. I used the same code for a JUnit test in another project where the exception does not occur instead an is returned. 
As I debugged into the Method getAudioInputStream(file) I found out that the exception is thrown because of getAudioFileReaders() returned an empty provider list. That is not the case in the other project in which my JUnit test is.

So I got two questions:
1. Why is the provider list empty?
2. Do I need to configure something in order to get at least one provider?

Comment: What Java version are you using? Your issue sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/25954052/119918

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out that **you cannot play .mp3 only with pure java API**
The AudioStream class does not supports mp3 natively.
You can check it on the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/AudioFileFormat.Type.html) for all the available formats

So i wonder how it's possible that on another computer you are able to run it,
if java itself doesn't allow it.

Comment: It could be that the OP did not cross-check the dependencies on the other computer. They might have the required library added to classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to open a .mp3, you need a Java SPI which adds the audio format support.
You can take a look at MP3SPI library from [Javazoom](http://www.javazoom.net/index.shtml) which would let you open mp3 files. They have VorbisSPI for ogg format support as well.